# Lotus Domino, registration new users script

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I'm noobie in the Lotus Domino 6.5, who i can registry new user without gui? (something script maybe?)
P.S. thanks and sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NotesRegistration class in LotusScript or lotus.domino.Registration class in Java code.

See [here for details](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESREGISTRATION_CLASS.html) -- but since that link goes to a more recent version (you are using a version of Domino that is almost ten years old, and has had no support from IBM for more than three years), you'll want to cross-check against the documentation that came with Domino Designer 6.5 in order to be sure about what's really available to you.

There is also a feature in the Domino Administrator client for providing a simple text file of user information in order to creates users in bulk.  You can look that up in the help file that comes with Domino Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You might also examine the Notes C API or Notes C++ API.  In the C API, there is a sample application called "userreg" which might help.